# What is the proper test for inter-rater reliability with three raters and ordinal ratings?

Tags: ordinal-data, reliability, agreement-statistics

I need help for choosing a proper test for inter-rater reliability. I have three raters (experts) who have analysed the quality of images (10 images from different location). The data is ordinal (image quality is assessed numerically from 1 to 5).

Answer (score 2):

For three raters and ordinal data, you can use a chance-adjusted agreement index with ordinal weights. Options include Conger's $\kappa$, Fleiss' $\kappa$, Bennett et al.'s $S$, Krippendorff's $\alpha$, and Gwet's $\gamma$.
These can be calculated in MATLAB using the [mReliability functions](http://mreliability.jmgirard.com/). They can also be calculated in R using the [irr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irr/index.html) or the [AgreeStat functions](http://agreestat.com/r_functions.html), sometimes with different names.